# how to get password from DialogCallbackHandler

Tags: java, digital-signature, digital-certificate

i'am working with gemalto SmartCard witch contain a digital certificate. i used DialogCallbackHandler to pass the PIN to have the possibility to load the keystore:

```
KeyStore.Builder ksBuilder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", provider, new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new DialogCallbackHandler()));
KeyStore ks = ksBuilder.getKeyStore();
ks.load(null, null);
```

The trouble is that the application is asking for the PIN for each document it has to sign, and it is not operative. is there any method to cash this PIN.